# Varying results when trying to handle errors in database login form

Tags: mysql, authentication, vbscript, error-handling, hta

I am making a application which will verify a login to a MySQL Server, which is being done with an `ADODB.Connection`, then open up another HTA if no errors are given. I am trying to achieve this using nothing but HTA, VBScript and hard work … Without going into too much detail, I would like to catch an error message which will come up if the user puts in the wrong username/password.

Normally,  if you do put in the wrong password or username, it comes up with a HTML Error message, which doesn't look very user friendly. That's what this code is trying to catch and make more friendly. Code segment below:

```
Sub MainLogin_click
  dim strError
  Uname = usertext.Value
  Pword = passtext.Value
  cstring = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver};SERVER=Localhost;UID=" & Uname _ 
    & ";PWD=" & Pword & ";DATABASE=maindb;"
  conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  On Error Resume Next
  conn.Open cstring
  Call MakeDSN
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    strError = "LongBow Error" & VbCrLf & " Error Number: " & Err.Number _
      & VbCrLf & " Error Source: " & Err.Source _
      & VbCrLf & " Error Description: " &  Err.Description
    MsgBox(strError)
    Err.Clear
  Else
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Run("bin\LongBowAgent.hta")
    Window.close
    conn.Close
  End If  
  On Error GoTo 0 
End Sub
```

Basically when I run this code, and my HTA as a whole, either

- Nothing happens, no activity when the 'login' button is pressed.

or

- I get a nice error box (even with the right username/password) saying 
  `Error 424, VBScript runtime error, object Required`.

Honestly - I've been at this for 2 days now and tried many things. None have really worked, but then Google Searching can only do so much.

Any Help, and any advise would be great. I do not mind trying something completely different here, so long as it stays within HTA & VBScript.

Comment: When error handling is enabled via `On Error Resume Next` you should check for error conditions after each statement as long error handling remains enabled. Which line is causing the error you observe? What does `MakeDSN` do?

Comment: Ok 'MakeDSN' does its name sake. It makes a DSN Connection. Second, I think I have made some progress. Please see my comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of your OERN is to large - it does not only hide errors of the .Open, but also problems in MakeDSN and in the error handling code.

Ironically, the first culprit is not covered by the OERN:

```
conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

is wrong, because you assign an object. Try

```
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

Comment: Ok, so I've edited my code slightly, also removed something which I feel very dumb about. First line after the <script> tag, was 'On Error Resume Next' . So yeah, my bad. Second, I have now edited the string so it has the Call MakeDSN inside the 'Else' Statement. Right, so far so good. However, now I get a blank msgbox when the wrong password is entered. Right pword/uname allows you in. any ideas?

Comment: Ok, so this is now working. Basically, I've added another check further up the page to check if the basebase connection is working, so now it the error you were going to get at this stage was username / password related.
Thanks to Ekkehard.Horner, your comments helped me understand how to get this working.